# Enzyme/Jest onSubmit not calling Submit Function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm having trouble checking if my mock action was called from an onSubmit on a form:

Login Form:

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    };
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.loginUser(this.state.email, this.state.password);
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    const { name } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { t } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="login-container>
        <form data-test-id="login-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <TextComponent
              label="Email"
              testId="login-email"
              value={this.state.email}
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <div className="my-3" />
            <TextComponent
              label="Password"
              testId="login-password"
              value={this.state.password}
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <button action="submit" data-test-id="login-button">
              {t("en.login")}
            </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    authenticated: state.login.authenticated,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ loginUser }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withTranslation()(Login));
```

Test:

```
import { mount, shallow, render } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { I18nextProvider } from "react-i18next";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { findByTestAtrr, testStore } from "../../test/utils/utils";
import Login from "../../src/Login/index";
import i18n from "../../src/i18n";
import history from "../../src/history";


const setUp = loginUser => {
  const initialState = {
    login: {
      authenticated: true,
    },
  };

  const store = testStore(initialState);
  const wrapper = mount(
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <Login onSubmit={loginUser} />
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    </I18nextProvider>
  );
  return wrapper;
};

  describe("submit button", () => {
    let emailInput;
    let passwordInput;
    let submitButton;
    let newWrapper;
    let loginAction;
    beforeEach(() => {
      loginAction = jest.fn();
      newWrapper = setUp(loginAction);

      emailInput = findByTestAtrr(newWrapper, "login-email");
      emailInput.instance().value = "email.com";
      emailInput.simulate("change");

      passwordInput = findByTestAtrr(newWrapper, "login-password");
      passwordInput.instance().value = "password";
      passwordInput.simulate("change");

      submitButton = findByTestAtrr(newWrapper, "login-button");
    });

    it("login action is called", () => {
      console.log(submitButton.debug());
      submitButton.simulate("submit");
      expect(loginAction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

I'm able to simulate adding values to the email and password but I can't simulate the onClick to work. Am I testing the submit function incorrectly?

This is my submit button when I console.log

```
console.log __tests__/integration_tests/login.test.js:97
  <button action="submit" data-test-id="login-button">
    Log in
  </button>
```

error:

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

```
Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `submitButton.simulate('click')`

Comment: doesn't work either :/

Comment: It may be that you are using enzyme to mount instead of the render method from react testing library? (just guessing since we cant see your imports)

Comment: @topched i updated the file. Yeah I'm using currently using mount

Comment: Shouldn't the button attribute be type instead of action? `<button type="submit" ...>...` Then if you are correctly targeting and simulating a click it should trigger the form's `onSubmit` callback.

Comment: @DrewReese that was a good point. I changed the code but it didn;t do anything :/

Comment: @lost9123193 is the test attribute correct? All the other components you target with `findByTestAtrr` use an attribute called `testId`, but on the button you use the data attribute `data-test-id`

Comment: @DrewReese yep I console.logged the button as seen above

Comment: @lost9123193 Did you ever check that you where using the correct attribute, i.e. `testId="login-button"` vs `data-test-id="login-button"`, on your button for testing?

Answer (score 3):

As raised from 2016 on github: [Simulated click on submit button in form does not submit form #308](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/308#issue-147094516), this issue still persists on my project, using Jest + Enzyme (2020).

There are some workarounds such as using `tape` or `sino`.

The other solution is to get the DOM element and trigger the click without using simulate (go to [given link](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/308#issue-147094516), scroll down the thread to learn more).

If anyone ever found a solution to simulate form submit, kindly tag me here. Thank you.

Comment: Just found out [Can't check if form submit works
#1722](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/1722#issuecomment-407322577) on enzyme github. Try to set props in form as suggested to see if it solves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the below mentioned link, you can use `done` and `setTimeout`.

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/21272#issuecomment-628607141

```
it('login action is called', (done) => {
  submitButton.simulate("submit");
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(loginAction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    done();
  }, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
it('should call onSubmit method', ()=>{

    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), "onSubmit");
    wrapper.find('button[type="submit"]').simulate('click');
   
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

});
```

Check the name of method to be called on simulate click. In my case it was onSubmit.
No need to import sinon or spy from sinon jest does everything.